# Weired problem after reading input from keyboard

Tags: java.util.scanner

edit: The ArrayList wasn't needed to reproduce the "error". Sorry for this delay, but know it should be much clearer.

Why is:

c2.number.equals(c3.number) = false

I really expected a true here. There must be something wrong with my equals method?

Why on earth do I need to write more text...

```
package com.example.mypackage;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Scanner;


class Contact {
    public String name;
    public String number;

    public Contact(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(name+number);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        } else if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (obj instanceof Contact) {
            Contact contact = (Contact) obj;
            if ((contact.name == this.name && contact.number == this.number)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}


public class Main {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Contact c1 = new Contact("ben", "1");
        c1.print();

        Contact c2 = new Contact("ben", "1");
        c2.print();

        System.out.println("name : ");
        String name=scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("number");
        String number=scanner.nextLine();
        Contact c3=new Contact(name, number);
        c3.print();

        System.out.println("c1.equals(c2) = "+c1.equals(c2));
        System.out.println("c3 instanceof Contact = "+(c3 instanceof Contact));
        System.out.println("c2.name.equals(c3.name) =  "+c2.name.equals(c3.name));
        System.out.println("c2.number.equals(c3.number) = "+c2.number.equals(c3.number));
        System.out.println("c2.number.equals(c3.number) = "+c3.equals(c2));
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
ben1
ben1
name : 
ben
number
1
ben1
c1.equals(c2) = true
c3 instanceof Contact = true
c2.name.equals(c3.name) =  true
c2.number.equals(c3.number) = true
c2.number.equals(c3.number) = false

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is:

c2.number.equals(c3.number) = false

I really expected a true here. There must be something wrong with my equals method?

Why on earth do I need to write more text...

Why is:

c2.number.equals(c3.number) = false

I really expected a true here. There must be something wrong with my equals method?

Why on earth do I need to write more text...

Why is:

c2.number.equals(c3.number) = false

I really expected a true here. There must be something wrong with my equals method?

Why on earth do I need to write more text...

Comment: Please show us the output, pasted as text into your question.

Comment: You need to add c2 and c3 to the list.

Comment: You're using == in your equals method to compare strings. You need to use super.equals().

Comment: Oh, thanks. Unfortunately I don't know how to give you an upvote for that.

Answer (score 0):

-1 is returned if it wasn't found in the list.

Did you forget to myList.add() it?

The only add I see is when you added c1.

You need to myList.add(c3) after you get the input, or it won't be in the list to find an index of.

Answer (score 0):

Ah finally I got it. The error is in the equals method.

I must use "equals()" instead of "==" there. For some reason this comparison does work with c1 and c2 but not with c3.

Comment: It works with the first two because they use constant strings, which use a string pool to store the constants.